# Getting a date of each month in a year from a day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I am trying to write a function so that it gets a date for example 10/31/2013. From this it take the day which is 31 and than starting with january it gives me list of 12 months date i.e

```
1/31/2013
2/30/2013
.....
...
12/31/2013
```

I can get the day part by using

```
            declare @day integer 
            set @day=day(GetDate());
```

I could use a while look to create for each month. But I am wondering if there is better way of doing it. Please help

Comment: are you getting dates from database in mm/dd/yyyy format , but you want the display to be in dd/mm/yyyy format ?

Comment: @misguided format is not problem. I wana get for each month the date from a day

Comment: I'd suggest using a while loop, and in the case of month ending dates (which is what this sounds like) using dateadd( -1 day) from the month start date of each following month to get the date you want

Comment: Can you explain where the days come from?  Meaning, where do you get 1/31 vs 2/30 vs 12/31?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @d date = '20130615'

select cast(dateadd(m, month, dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, @d), -1)) as date) 
from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) x(month)
```

EDIT after @Kaf's comment: Ok, I just assumed it was the last day, It works as I intended, but most likely not as mr J.Davidson intended. That just makes the script easier to write:

```
select cast(dateadd(m, month - month(@d), @d) as date) 
from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) x(month)
```

Comment: Agreed; adding it to the initial date repeatedly is probably the correct option.

Comment: This gives same results regardless of the date part of the passing date, *I think* (not sure tho) he needs to get date of each month with the dame datepart of passing variable. Ex; `@date = '201306xy' => 201301xy,(max day for feb if xy > max feb day) ,201303xy,...,201312xy`

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I tend to prefer recursive solutions too, although the simplicity of @t-clausen's answer is appealing.  Note that you can't simply add a single month repeatedly, given the way the month lengths fluctuate (... and February regularly throws everybody off...).  I think I might have tried something like this:

```
WITH Cycle_Dates (startOn, cycleStart, monthsElapsed)
                 as (SELECT startOn, startOn, 1
                     FROM Cycle
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT startOn, DATEADD(month, monthsElapsed, startOn), monthsElapsed + 1
                     FROM Cycle_Dates
                     WHERE monthsElapsed < 13)
SELECT cycleStart
FROM Cycle_Dates
```

(I now consider it necessary for me to post [SQL Fiddle examples](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61e356/2) where possible, to help keep me honest).

Comment: as far as i can tell, we are suppose to find all months within the same year. Also you have 13 months. Try your script with the date '2013-05-15' as input

Comment: Hm, I guess that could be an issue, if the OP want's past dates.  It'd be trivial for it to be modified for 'in current year only' behavior.  Really, though, I was assuming this was being used similarly to billing cycles, and so a full year would be needed (including 'next' year).